# What are the houses in Durmstrang?

Tags: harry-potter

In comparison with Beauxbatons Academy of Magic, I could not determine what the Houses are nor how the Sorting happens at the Durmstrang Institute Wizarding School. Does anyone have any ideas? If not, are there presumptions or have suitable names ever been created?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Not known (currently)

We don't know if Durmstrang has "houses". No mention has been made in any of the canon writings; books, films, games, Top Trumps cards, twitters, interview or any of the other material released in the Harry Potter universe.

We do know that the school itself is relatively small (just four storeys high) so there's a very real possibility that all of the students are simply roomed in adjoining dormitories.

---

For the record, we also don't know whether Beauxbatons has any houses either. Apparently it's rather larger so there's more of a possibility but it's more of a British tradition than a French one, so it's really anyone's guess at this point in time. JKR isn't saying and the only "houses" we see are those from fanfic.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond! I did not know these details and what you say is true, this is all we can deduce at this moment.. Ah even Beauxbatons; I had retrieved my knowledge from this site [LINK](http://beauxbatonsacademyx.weebly.com/houses.html), which I now realize is unofficial due to being from a roleplay community. Nevertheless I think it is because I originally found the made-up houses convincing and fitting, as if from J.K. Rowling herself.

Comment: @aitía - If you found the answer useful, you can mark it as "accepted" by clicking the tick to the left.